# Jackson: ignore the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class that I serialize and I use the  `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at the class level to exclude some fields from it.

Lately I have an use case where I need those fields serialized.

Is there a way to make a writer/reader that ignores the annotation?

I was looking into `@JsonView` but it seems `@JsonIgnoreProperties` takes precedence over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution, don't know if it the best one but gets the job done ...

I ended up using @JsonView.

So I have 2 views like this:

```
public class Views {
    public  static class Public { }
    public  static class Extended extends Public { }
}
```

and the default Spring mapper configured as

```
  mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.Public.class));
  mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
```

and the class looks like

```
 public class Foo{
        String name;
        @JsonView(Views.Extended.class)
        String title;
...}
```

By setting up a default view on the object mapper it causes it to ignore all the other not specified views. The fields with no annotation will always be serialized, as per config.

Then, when I need the whole class to be serialized I use:

```
objectMapper.writer().withView(Views.Extended.class).writeValueAsString(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

@JsonFilter could help you in this case.

By defining custom json filter, Jackson will dynamically resolve filter given class uses, dynamically, allowing per-call reconfiguration of filtering.

You can find detailed explanation and usage example [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html)

Some usefull information about dynamic ignoral you find [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)